# react-navigation for react native sending to wrong screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a react-native app for iOS and Android. 
I'm using react-navigation to deal with routing and navigation as follows:

```
const AppDrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Screens.Auth.Login,
        path: '/login'
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Screens.Auth.Register,
        path: '/register'
    },
    Forgotten: {
        screen: Screens.Auth.Forgotten,
        path: '/forgotten'
    },

    Profile: {
        screen: Screens.Profile,
        path: '/profile'
    }
})
```

And then I render this in React

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppDrawerNavigation persistenceKey="AppDrawerNavigationState2"  />

    }
}
```

Worked fine at the beginning but now when I navigate it sends me to the wrong page or refers to pages that I have removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the persistence. It is remembering routes that it has stored. 
For safety, everytime you add, remove and/or change the routing, you should change the `persistenceKey` to erase the it's previous value and store again.

Example:

```
<AppDrawerNavigation persistenceKey="AppDrawerNavigationState"  />
```

to

```
<AppDrawerNavigation persistenceKey="AppDrawerNavigationState1"  />
```

*I added a "1" at the end of my persistenceKey name*

Comment: Documentation link may be useful for someone https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html#warning-route-router-definition-changes